# Windows services installation / uninstallation in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, service, installation

I have an application, in `C++`, which attempts, upon running (at which time, no other relevant process is thought to be running), to install a couple of services.

The workflow is that if the services exist, then they are uninstalled, else they and uninstalled and then re-installed.

I had followed a few tutorials like : 
[Installing a service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683500(v=vs.85).aspx)

Unfortunately, something seems to go wrong with the installation or the uninstallation.

Upon assuming that the service is not installed, when I proceed to install the services, they get installed, and I then attempt to change the configuration, to delayed-Auto start.

At this stage, although the services are installed, I cannot start them, as I get the error saying services cannot be found.

When I try uninstalling the services, the uninstallation fails, giving an error 1060, saying the services are marked for deletion.

```
SC_HANDLE schSCManager;
SC_HANDLE schService;

schSCManager = OpenSCManager(
    NULL,                    // local computer
    NULL,                    // ServicesActive database 
    SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  // full access rights 

if (schSCManager == nullptr)
{
    continue;
}
if (bInstall)
{
    schService = CreateService(
        schSCManager,              // SCM database 
        szServiceName,                   // name of service 
        szDisplayName,                   // service name to display 
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,        // desired access 
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, // service type 
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START,      // start type 
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,      // error control type 
        szDirectory,                    // path to service's binary 
        NULL,                      // no load ordering group 
        NULL,                      // no tag identifier 
        NULL,                      // no dependencies 
        NULL,                      // LocalSystem account 
        NULL);                     // no password 

    if (schService == NULL)
    {
        TraceAdvice(L"CreateService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());

        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!ChangeServiceConfig(
            schService,            // handle of service 
            SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,     // service type: no change 
            SERVICE_CONFIG_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO,  // service start type 
            SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,     // error control: no change 
            NULL,                  // binary path: no change 
            NULL,                  // load order group: no change 
            NULL,                  // tag ID: no change 
            NULL,                  // dependencies: no change 
            NULL,                  // account name: no change 
            NULL,                  // password: no change 
            NULL))                // display name: no change
        {
            TraceAdvice(L"ChangeServiceConfig failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        }
        TraceAdvice(L"Service installed successfully\n");
    }

    CloseServiceHandle(schService);
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
    /*TraceFatal(_T("Now installing : %s"), szServiceName);
    _stprintf_s(szTmp, _T("SC create %s binpath= \"%s%s.exe\" displayName= \"%s\"  start= delayed-auto"), szServiceName, szDirectory, szServiceName, szDisplayName);
    TraceFatal(_T("Command is : %s"), szTmp);*/
}
else
{

    _wsystem(_T("taskkill /F /IM mmc.exe")); // Need to kill any instance of MMC running
    _wsystem(_T("taskkill /F /IM procexp.exe")); 

    schService = OpenService(
        schSCManager,       // SCM database 
        szServiceName,          // name of service 
        DELETE);            // need delete access 

    if (schService == NULL)
    {
        TraceAdvice(L"OpenService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        continue;
    }

    DWORD dwBytesNeeded;
    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS ssp;

    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(
        schService,
        SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,
        (LPBYTE)&ssp,
        sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS),
        &dwBytesNeeded))
    {
        printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    }
    if (ssp.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING)
    {
        _stprintf_s(szTmp, _T("taskkill /F /IM %s.exe"), szServiceName);
        _wsystem(szTmp);
    }
    // Delete the service.

    if (!DeleteService(schService))
    {
        TraceAdvice(L"DeleteService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else TraceAdvice(L"Service deleted successfully\n");

    CloseServiceHandle(schService);
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
}
```

}

I made sure of all the points, viz.

- Task manager was closed
- Service console was closed.
- All instances of MMC were closed.
- Service was stopped
- Service was not open in debugger in Visual Studio...

But it does not avail. The service does not get uninstalled till I reboot the system (deleting the registry linked to the service does not work either).

I have checked the parameters I pass on to these functions, and they seem correct.

What else should I be checking for, to ensure a correct installation, or a successful uninstallation?

Comment: What makes you think you need to kill mmc instances?  That's a pretty horrible thing to be doing to the end user!

Comment: More information, please.  How are you attempting to start the service, and what is the *exact* error message?  Are you sure that `szDirectory` contains the *full* path to the service executable, and not (as the variable name would suggest) just the path to the directory the service executable is in?  When uninstalling, what is the result of the call to QueryServiceStatusEx?

Comment: Also, what does TraceAdvice() do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the service first, otherwise it gets stuck in this pending delete state.  Forcibly killing the service is not the same thing as stopping it.  From the same area of [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686335(v=vs.85).aspx), you need to `ControlService(SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)`.